# Symfony2.1 - The option "em" does not exist when using DataTransformer

Tags: symfony-2.1, data-transfer-objects

I am using [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) cookbook recipe to add a data transformer in Symfon 2.1, but I am getting the following error, `The option "em" does not exist. Known options are: "attr", "block_name",....`

Is this still a valid way to send the entity manager over to the form type?

```
$taskForm = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(
    'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(),
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can't comment if that's the best way or not, I've always passed them to my task constructor as a hard dependency...

**Services**

```
services:
    my_bundle.form.type.task:
        class: Company\MyBundle\Form\Type\TaskType
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

**Controller**

```
$form = $this->createForm($this->get('my_bundle.form.type.task'), $task);
// or
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()));
```

**Form Type**

```
namespace Company\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
// ...

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    // ...
}
```

As soon as my form types have any dependencies, I use the container to manage them. I personally find this method much more clear of what's going on, and what my custom classes require than relying on Symfony's complex form configuration to do it for me.

Comment: If you add a tag to your DI configuration you can simplify your controller to $this->createForm('my_bundle_task', $task). See [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service).

Comment: ```$form = $this->createForm($this->get('my_bundle.form.type.task'), $task);
// or
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()));```

I don't get it. You can't pass the task AND the EntityManager as arguments ?

Answer (score 9):

To make the first simple (without dependency injection) Transformer's cookbook recipe work you should  add "em" as a known option. You can add it in your form's type class (TaskType in cookbook case) using `setRequired()` method like this:

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType {
    //...
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {   
        //...other stuff like $resolver->setDefaults(... if you need it

        $resolver->setRequired(array('em'));
    }
}
```

Adding 'em' with $resolver->setDefaults() would also work, but in this cookbook case entity manager is needed and so using setRequired() seems better.

Answer (score 2):

dont forget

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
    ));

    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'em',
    ));

    $resolver->setAllowedTypes(array(
        'em' => 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager',
    ));
```