# Best way to validate entity by unique key in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to build a form gathering information about new player in a game.

To start a game one need to provide nickname, email and a code.

Codes are stored in another table connected with player table with one-to-one relation

What I need to do during validation is to check if provided token exists and if so store *Player* id in *Code* record.

To do that I'm trying to build a form:

```
class PlayerType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('code','text')
        ->add('email', 'email') 
        ->add('nick', 'text')
    ;
}
...
}
```

but in that way during validation (or probably during creating instance of Code)

```
Argument 1 passed to Player::setCode() must be an instance of Code, string given
```

which is obvious since string has been provided.

What to do to perform a lookup during form validation and pass not token string but token instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). This will let you to create a form with a scalar type field that gets transformed into an entity when populating the model on a form submit.

Regarding the validation, you'll need to create a [custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) that checks if the given code exists in the database.

Comment: pretty cool and it makes perfect sense but that example dosn't seen to work:
I get The option "em" does not exist. Known options are: "attr", "block_name", ... Any ideas?

Comment: found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605530/symfony2-1-the-option-em-does-not-exist-when-using-datatransformer